# How can I ask Siri what my current cell phone number is?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

I generally buy a new SIM card each time I arrive in a new country, so when I'm traveling, my phone number tends to change. I can find out what my number is by Settings>Phone>My Number, but it'd often be more convenient to get it from Siri. I can't figure out how to get Siri to give it to me. None of these queries works:

- What is my cell phone number?
- What is my mobile phone number?
- What is this phone's number?
- What is the phone number for this SIM card?

What's the proper incantation to get Siri to tell me my iPhone's telephone number?

Answer (score 2):

As a one time incident take the number from Settings>Phone>Number and save it as a contact, you can then quickly get Siri to give it to you when required.

Answer (score 0):

"What's my phone number" just worked for me.

She replied, "You have phone numbers for iPhone & work" & both were listed below.

Comment: Only works when the number is stored in the "Me" contact.

Comment: I thought that may be the case, but have no way to test - I've had the same phone number since the 80s ;-)

Comment: +1 for calling out the “me” contact card option.

Answer (score 0):

Siri doesn't retrieve the contents of a sim / device identifying information, so you need to tap the settings app and navigate to the phone portion of that app.

- Why not put the text of your number on your lock screen and just look at it?

For most people, Siri listens and responds when the phone is locked, so restricting the information she will divulge is less likely because it can't be done and more likely a conscious design limitation for securing the data on the device.

The only loophole would be if you allow contacts lookup from Siri and self identify your card. Barring that, you could use voiceover to navigate there and hear what is set or you could ask Siri to dial 804-222-1111 and use that or similar service to check your caller ID.

Comment: That's a rather backwards way to get data that's already stored on the phone. It's also not practical, because it would require that I figure out how to do this in every country I visit.

Comment: Swapping SIM is a manual process, so I can see how if this request were delivered to engineering for the things Siri needs to do for the next release, it would likely be dismissed compared to things most users will need on a daily basis. I don't doubt you feel this is something Apple should do, but my answer reflects what the status is and offers a solution you could use if you cannot manipulate the phone to navigate to the settings app to retrieve that information in visual format.

Comment: The fundamental surprise is that Siri doesn't seem to know about the settings of the phone it's running on. What kind of personal assistant doesn't know what's in its office?

Comment: Or Siri is potentially available from a locked phone and Apple chose to not leak very personal information for all phones when some small fraction of people might want this. Just because you can do something, doesn’t make it the right call @KnowItAllWannabe